# Ubuntu 18.04 installed from USB boots straight to Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 downloaded from the Ubuntu website and booted to a USB drive. Then I formatted E: drive for Ubuntu and installed successfully, but when I start my laptop it boots straight to Windows 10.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: If UEFI then open boot settings and make sure Ubuntu is selected.

Comment: @MuhammadSalmanKhan ubuntu cannot write grub if quick hibernate isn't first disabled in windows. open a powershell as administrator, type `powercfg -h off` then reboot and install ubuntu again and use "something else" in the install choices to format over the partition that had ubuntu and install ubuntu there. or use "try" instead of "install" on the liveUSB and run this command in a terminal : `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y boot-repair boot-info` but in both cases you need to turn off windows quick hibernate first.